# Numpy: Generate grid according to density function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

`linspace` generates a linear space. How can I generate a grid using an arbitrary density function?

Say, I would like to have a grid from 0 to 1, with 100 grid points, and where the density of points is given by `(x - 0.5)**2` - how would I create such a grid in Python?

**That is, I want many grid-points where the function `(x - 0.5)**2)` is large, and few points where the function is small**. I do *not* want a grid that has values according to this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case the following solution should work. Be sure that `func` is positive throughout the range...

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def func(x):
    return (x-0.5)**2

start = 0
end = 1
npoints = 100

x = np.linspace(start,end,npoints)
fx = func(x)

# take density (or intervals) as inverse of fx
# g in [0,1] controls how much warping you want.
# g = 0: fully warped
# g = 1: linearly spaced
g = 0 
density = (1+g*(fx-1))/fx

# sum the intervals to get new grid
x_density = np.cumsum(density)
# rescale to match old range
x_density -= x_density.min()
x_density/= x_density.max()
x_density *= (end-start)
x_density += start


fx_density = func(x_density)

plt.plot(x,fx,'ok',ms = 10,label = 'linear')
plt.plot(x_density,fx_density,'or',ms = 10,label = 'warped')
plt.legend(loc = 'upper center')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For example like this:

```
x = (np.linspace(0.5,1.5,100)-0.5)**2
```

The start and end values have to be chosen so that `f(start) = 0` and `f(end)=1`.